# Quasi ideal sequence in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

According to comments by Hamza I revise the question.

Let $H$ be  an infinite dimensional  separable Hilbert space.

Is there an  increasing sequence of subvector spaces $V_{1} \subsetneq V_{2} \subsetneq  \ldots \subsetneq V_{n} \ldots $ of $B(H)$ such that each $V_{n}$ is a closed subspace  and is closed under $*-$operation.(Say  operator system) Moreover we have $$  B(H)V_{n} \subset V_{n+1}$$

that is $ax \in V_{n+1}$  if  $a\in B(H),\;\;x\in V_{n}$

Comment: I don't think that will be true for another case than ($V_k={0}$ for $k\leq n_0$ and $V_k=H$ for $k>n_0$)

Comment: @Hamza  what is  a reason of such finiteness?

Comment: If you take $H$ as a finite dimensional hilbert space (euclidien) (dim H=n) you know that $B(H)= M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and we know that for any two finite dimensional space $V_n$ and $E\leq H$ (non trivial) there exists a matrix which transform $V_n$ to $E$ so the cycle will be in this case : ${0} \qquad V_n \qquad H$. (and we can't repeat $V_n$ in this sequence)

Comment: @Hamza In my question I actually mean infinite dimensional hilbert space.   I revise the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the subspaces being selfadjoint, $B(H)V_1\subset V_2$ implies that $V_1B(H)\subset V_2$. If $V_1\ne0$, then $B(H)V_1B(H)\subset V_3$ contains all finite-rank operators, and thus $V_3$, being closed, contains the compact operators.

If $V_3$ contains a non-compact operator, then the ideas in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1070875/22857) show that $I\in V_7$ (I didn't count carefully, so this might be off by one or two; the point is that every multiplication by a new element pushes you up one step on subspace in the chain), so $V_8=B(H)$.

These ideas can probably be used to argue that the chain has to be even shorter; I'm afraid I don't have the time now.