# Closed ideals of $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be separable Hilbert space.I’m trying to prove that

> The only  proper closed ideal of $B(H)$ is $K(H)$, the compact operators on $H$

I can see that every closed ideal of $B(H)$ must contain $K(H)$ but I cannot see the other part.

I’m sure that that there must be many books which contains proof of this result but I could not find any. Any references which has proper  proof of the same fact?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070874/the-ideal-generated-by-a-non-compact-operator).