# Every *-isometric isomorphism of $B(\mathcal{H})$ keep compact operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $B(\mathcal{H})$ denotes the $\mathcal{C}^*$-algebra consisting of bounded linear transformation on $\mathcal{H}$ ($*$ is the adjoint). Now consider a isometric *-isomorphism of $B(\mathcal{H})$ onto it self namely $\phi$. If $K$ is a compact operator, then $\phi(K)$ is also compact. Is this claim true?

---

Here are my thoughts: (I guess it is right)
1.Maybe we can consider finite-rank operators. If we can prove $\phi$ keeps rank-one operators, then it will keep finite-rank operators, and thus keep compact operators by the density and continuity. 
2.The ideal $\mathcal{K}$ formed by all compact operators is a minimal nonzero closed ideal of $B(\mathcal{H})$, and $\phi(\mathcal{K})$ is a closed ideal of $B(\mathcal{H})$. So if we can prove $\phi(\mathcal{K})\cap \mathcal{K}\not= \varnothing$, then $\phi(\mathcal{K})=\mathcal{K}$ and the claim is true.

---

I think this question is not too difficult, but I just sticked. It also helpful if you can give me some hints or references. Thanks.

Comment: Projections onto one-dimensional subspaces are exactly the minimal projections (i.e. projections $p\neq 0$ such that $q\leq p$, $q\neq 0$ implies $p=q$). This property is of course preserved under $\ast$-automorphisms. You can use this to follow your strategy 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a corollary of the fact that every $*$-automorphism of $\mathbb B(\mathcal H)$ is inner, and the hint given by MaoWao can also be used to prove this.  I'll expand on this hint a bit.

Indeed, if $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb B(\mathcal H)$, then minimal projections are mapped to minimal projections under $\phi$.  Thus to each unit vector $\xi\in\mathcal H$, $\phi(\xi\otimes\xi)$ is also a minimal projection, hence is of the form $(u\xi)\otimes(u\xi)$ for some unit vector $u\xi\in\mathbb B(\mathcal H)$.  Then the map $\xi\mapsto u\xi$ extends to a unitary $u\in\mathbb B(\mathcal H)$, and it follows that $\phi=\operatorname{ad}(u)$.

Comment: Thanks Aweygan. I think this proof is more simple, and the claim that every *-automorphsim of $B(\mathcal{H})$ is inner is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Note that a $*$-isomorphisms is automatically isometric.

- If $p$ is a rank-one projection, then it is minimal (and viceversa). Then $\phi(p)$ is also a minimal projection, so it is also a rank-one projection. A selfadjoint compact operator $x$ is a norm-limit of linear combinations of rank-one projections, and this will be preserved by $\phi$. So $\phi$ maps compact selfadjoints to compact selfadjoints. Now any compact $x$ is, by the polar decomposition, $x=vr$, with $r$ positive. Since $r=(x^*x)^{1/2}$, it is compact. So $\phi(x)=\phi(v)\phi(r)$ is compact.
- Much easier than the above, when $H$ is separable: since $\phi$ is a $*$-isomorphism, it preserves ideals. And $K(H)$ is the only nontrivial (closed, bilateral) ideal.

Comment: Thanks Martin, may I ask where can I find the proof of your last claim?

Comment: It's mentioned everywhere, I guess, but the proof is easy enough that it is often left as an exercise. First you prove that  any (closed, bilaterial) ideal contains all compact operators (easy exercise). Then you show that [if an ideal contains a non-compact operator, then it is all of $B(H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1070874/22857).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for MaoWao’s hint. The answer is affirmative. Now I finish the details.

(When I type this, Aweygan gives his answer)

---

Observation 1: $\phi$ keeps the spectrum, and thus keeps the positive operators. Indeed, since $\phi$ algebraic isomorphism, $(\lambda-T)A=id$ iff. $(\lambda-\phi(T))\phi(A)=id$. So $\lambda\in \rho(T)$ iff. $\lambda\in  \rho(T)$. $\phi$ keeps the spectrum implies $\phi$ keeps the positive operators (a operator $A$ is positive iff. $(Ax,x)\geq 0$ iff. $\sigma(A)\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$).

Observation 2: for orthogonal projective operators $P$ and $Q$. $(Px,x)\leq (Qx,x)$ iff. $Ran(P)\subseteq Ran(Q)$. (easy exercise)

Observation 3: $\phi^{-1}$ is also a $\mathcal{C}^*$-isomorphism. So above still holds if we replace $\phi$ by $\phi^{-1}$.

---

Suppose $Q$ is a rank-one orthogonal projection. Then $$\phi(Q)^2=\phi(Q^2)=\phi(Q), \hspace{0.3cm} \phi(Q)^*=\phi(Q^*)=\phi(Q).$$ Thus $\phi(Q)$ is an orthogonal projection. To see $\phi(Q)$ is rank-one, it’s sufficient to see it is minimal. If there is some orthogonal projection $P$ such that $(Px,x)\leq (\phi(Q)x,x)$. By above discussion and observation 3, $\phi^{-1}(P)$ is orthogonal projection. Note $\phi(Q)-P$ is positive, use observation 1 with $\phi^{-1}$ yields $Q-\phi^{-1}(P)$ is positive. Then use observation 2 with $\phi^{-1}$ yields $Ran(\phi^{-1}(P))\subseteq Q$, hence $\phi^{-1}(P)=Q$ and $P=\phi(Q)$. This proves $\phi(Q)$ is minimal. Consequently $\phi$ keeps rank-one orthogonal projections.
Every (bounded) rank-one operator is a scalar of rank-one orthogonal projections, so $\phi$ keeps rank-one operators. And it follows by my strategy 1.